# how to autosize excel cells while copying data from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i am exporting sql data into excel using stored procedure..
while opening the excel few cell values are partially hidden, i want to resize it including the header..
and want to make the header bolder..
plz help me out to solve this issue..

### sql stored procedure:

```
alter procedure usp_example         
 (                
 @db_name varchar(100),                
 @schm_name varchar(100),                
 @table_name varchar(100),                 
 @file_name varchar(100)                
  )                
 as          


--Generate column names as a recordset                
  declare @columns varchar(8000), @sql varchar(8000) ,  
   @sql1 varchar(8000), @data_file varchar(100)           

   select                       
    @columns=coalesce(@columns+',','')+column_name+' as '+column_name                       
    from                       
    information_schema.columns                      
    where                       
    table_name=@table_name       

    select @columns=''''+replace(replace(@columns,' as ',''' as '),',',',''')                           


    --Create a dummy file to have actual data                
     select @data_file=substring(@file_name,1,len(@file_name)-              
     charindex('\',reverse(@file_name)))+'\data_file.csv'                


      --Generate column names in the passed EXCEL file                
       set @sql='bcp " select ''DATE'', *,''SHIFT'' ,''SETUPTIME'' from (select '+@columns+') as t" queryout   c:\Daily_Reports\daily_machinedescription_report_summary.csv  -c -t,  -T -S ' + @@servername                
        exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql               
        print @sql             



     --Generate data in the dummy file        

    set @sql='bcp "SELECT convert(varchar, ENTRY_DATE, 105) as DATE ,machinename as Machine,RunTime,ECTime,ReworkTime as RWTime,IdleTime,DownTime,SHIFT_TYPE as Shift,SetupTime  FROM VentureBI_Prod_Test..view_admin_report ORDER BY segment " queryout   c:\Daily_Reports\data_file.csv  -c -t,  -T -S' + @@servername                

     exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql          



      --Copy dummy file to passed EXCEL file              
     set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''type '+@data_file+' >> "'+@file_name+'"'''              
     exec(@sql)               


         ----Delete dummy file               
       set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''del '+@data_file+''''              
       exec(@sql)
```

[image]

Regards,

T.Navin

### Error while saving Macro Code:

[image]

Comment: You can format the excel file with c# afterwords. I don't know if it's possible to do it with the bcp..

Comment: i am running the sp in sql job  scheduler

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are transferring the data as csv (from your code). csv files can not be formatted.

You can convert the csv file to xlsx or xls in your programming lang of choice afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert formatting information into a CSV file which is what you require. The CSV file can only contain data. See

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-formatting-and-features-that-are-not-transferred-to-other-file-formats-HP010014105.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010099725#BM4

You could try a different file format that Excel can open, for instance using xml, however that isn't easy and it will require headers and footers that aren't trivial to generate in a proc.

I know that you just said that you're running the sp from a scheduler so this may not be an option for you, but you could consider creating an Excel file and then running the proc from Excel and inserting the results into a pre-formatted spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know so far (willing to learn something new regarding this, though) the only way I get this done is to pre-format the excel file and use templates.

However, you can also run this if macro usage is not an issue:

```
Option Explicit 

Sub AutoFitAllColumns() 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    Dim strWorksheetName As String 
    Dim objWorkBook As Worksheet 

    strWorksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name 

    For Each objWorkBook In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
        On Error Resume Next 
        objWorkBook.Activate 
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit 
    Next objWorkBook

    Sheets(strWorksheetName).Select 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AutoFitAllColumns
End Sub
```

Make sure that the code is in the excel file that you use as a template, then make a copy of it first. Thing is.. I'm not sure what will happen if you use it to open .csv files using excel. Maybe you can try?

Comment: i have pasted this code, and tried to save it..but its showing error..i have attached the screen shot of the error on the top..plz chk it

Comment: @navbingo , have you tried manually resizing the columns before saving the .csv file? I'm not sure yet but maybe you're getting that prompt because normally, no meta data / extra information get saved in the plainest of plainest .csv files..:( When you get that prompt next time you use the VBA code to format it click 'yes' and see what happens..